# PHP: Phpstan class_implements call interface method: Call to an undefined method

Tags: php, phpstan

I have a method in an abstract parent class. The behaviour basically depends on wether the child class inherits an interface or not.

How can I make phpstan recognize this conditional (in this case "class_implements")

```
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);

interface Displayable {
    public function display(): string;  
}

abstract class ParentClass
{
    public function run(): string {
        if (in_array(Displayable::class, class_implements(static::class))) {
            return $this->display();
        }

        return '';
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass implements Displayable {

    public function display(): string {
        return 'dis';
    }
}
```

phpstan produces the error:

> Call to an undefined method ParentClass::display().

Comment: Please post a [mre] in the question, not at a remote link.

Comment: Don't know if it will help, but maybe `if (in_array("display", get_class_methods($this)))`

Comment: Nope - same behaviour

Comment: Handling dynamic conditions is generally difficult in static analyzers.

Comment: No idea if it will make any difference, but try changing `class_implements(static::class)` to `class_implements($this)`. Maybe PHPStan doesn't realize that `static::class` and `$this` are interchangeable in that context (since you check `static::class` but are using `$this->display()` after). I've seen similar "false-positive-errors" in IDE's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask `$this instanceof Displayable`.

See supported ways of narrowing types: https://phpstan.org/writing-php-code/narrowing-types